# Springboot app image not working on aws ecs

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am learning AWS ECS. In continuation to it, I created a sample application with the following Dockerfile config

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11
ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/springboot-practice-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

The app has just one endpoint `/employee` which returns a hardcoded value at the moment.

1. I built this image locally and ran it successfully using command
   `docker run -p 8080:8080 -t chandreshv85/demo`
2. Pushed it to docker respository
3. Created a fargate cluster and task definition
4. Created a task in running state based on the above definition.

Now when I try to access the endpoint it's giving 404.
Suspecting that something could be wrong with the security group, I created a different task definition based on another image (another repo) and it ran fine with the same security group.

Now, I believe that something is wrong with the springboot image. Can someone please help me identify what is wrong here? Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: You need to look at the container's logs in CloudWatch Logs to see what the actual error is. You may need to increase the logging level of Spring Boot and redeploy if you don't see enough detail in the current logs. There's really no way for anyone to help you given the amount of information you have provided in your question, since the problem is obviously in the Spring Boot app and you have provided a total of 0 information on your spring boot app.

Comment: Is the 404 returning from the Spring app? You would not get a 404 if this was a SecurityGroup issue.

Comment: You say you are running it local mapping 8080:8080. Are you overriding the spring web port in the Task Definition to something else like 80? Perhaps posting your TaskDefinition Json might help.

Comment: Thank you @HermannSteidel This helped. It was the port overriding. I see that the container port was mapped to 80 and springboot was using 8080 and hence the mismatch. The issue was resolved after using ```server.port=80``` in the springboot application. 

In task definition I was using both mapping

``` portMappings: [
        {
          "hostPort": 8080,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 8080
        },
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ] ```